# extends React.Component vs extends Component

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react and I have seen people using

```
class X extends Component {}
```

and

```
class X extends React.Component {}
```

**When to use one or the other?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both way is fine.The difference is depend on how you import Componet.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
class X extends Component {}
```

or

```js
import React from 'react'
class X extends React.Component {}
```

Personally, I prefer the first way.